# Excel - Extracting data from multiple csv files conditionally

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have many .csv files which has data in the format of:

```
Time        data1       data2      data3
0:00:00     1.22        1.23       432
0:01:00     1.52        1.13       432
0:02:00     1.12        1.15       431
```

However some of the csv files have skipped time slots such as:

```
Time        data1       data2      data3
0:00:00     1.22        1.23       432
0:03:00     1.71        1.43       431
0:04:00     1.79        1.54       432
```

The data comes from a machine surveillance system which collects data periodically. It skips certain time slots when it is turned off or has problems. I want to extract a specific row say **data2** from all the csv files into an xlsx file, while leaving time slots that were skipped to be empty cells such as:

```
Time        data2       data2      
0:00:00     1.23        1.23       
0:01:00     1.13                   
0:02:00     1.15                   
0:03:00     1.22        1.43       
0:04:00     1.71        1.54
```

Am not familiar with excel macros/VBA but would appreciate any advice on how to approach this problem, thanks!

Comment: Are these csv files assumed to be already open in a workbook or are we supposed to code that for you?

Comment: @Jeeped sorry i don't quite understand your question, could you clarify it a bit more?

Comment: No worries. I don't think we are on the same page, so to speak.

Comment: We can help you best if you can bring us specific questions about problems you're trying to solve with you code. So in your case, start by researching how to open a CSV file with a VBA macro, and parse it into different variables (maybe building an array). Next, you'll take the data you've read and save those values to a range of cells in a spreadsheet. After that, you might be sorting (by the timestamps probably). So take it step by step and then come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: @PeterT alright thanks will look into it, much appreciated

Comment: This can be accomplished using an `Union` query. Something like `(SELECT [File1]![Time],  [File1]![data2] FROM [Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\1.csv;
Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Fixed"";]) AS File1 UNION `SELECT ([File2]![Time],  [File2]![data2A] FROM [Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\2.csv;
Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Fixed"";]) As File2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read specific content from a CSV like this.

```
Sub sbADO()
Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

DBPath = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\"

sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"

Conn.Open sconnect
    sSQLSting = "SELECT * From CSV1.csv WHERE ID = 2"
    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
    'Close Recordset
    mrs.Close

Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Or, merge all date from all CSV files, and delete what you don't want/need.

```
Sub AnalysisMerger2()
    Dim WSA As Worksheet
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim SelectedFiles As Variant
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, vDB As Variant, rngT As Range
    Dim vFn, myFn As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsEmpty(SelectedFiles) Then Exit Sub

    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
        vFn = Split(FileName, "\")
        myFn = vFn(UBound(vFn))
        myFn = Replace(myFn, ".csv", "")
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(FileName, Format:=2)
        Set WSA = bookList.Sheets(1)
        vDB = WSA.UsedRange
        bookList.Close (0)
        Set Ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        ActiveSheet.Name = myFn
        Ws.Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```